# Decode some value stored in mySQL and separate them for form

Tags: php

I have a database which contains some values in a field. It contains values which i'm trying to decode for them to be used in a select form.

The values are like this:

```
MEAL:YES::-::Yes::-*-::MEAL:NO::-::No
```

In this example, the select form should have two possibilities.

MEAL:YES  is what is written, and Yes is the value
they are separated by  `::-::`

The first select option and 2nd one are separated by `::-*-::`

Comment: This looks very confusing... Why can't the DB have something like `MEAL:YES` or `MEAL:NO`? Can't change that data? Also, can you send other variants as well? Like for Meal No and Yes and not selected, if available?

Comment: You just need to explode() the value into what you want

Comment: Use `explode('::-*-::', $value)` to get all the possibilities.

Comment: No, @Barmar, that only solves half problem, whereas my previous comment was meant to: `foreach (explode('::-*-::', $a) as $item) { list($key, $value) = explode('::-::', $item); $data[$key] = $value; }
`

Answer (score 0):

like @Bermar said
use

$possible_values = explode('::-*-::', $mySQL-value-coming-from-db)

and then `var_dump($possible_values)` once you've got the values from db. You can change what needs to be displayed in what order.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (explode('::-*-::', $raw_data) as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('::-::', $item);
    $data[$key] = $value;
}
```

Result will be like:

```
Array
(
    [MEAL:YES] => Yes
    [MEAL:NO] => No
)
```